# Quarto make long text fit into one slide with revealjs

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

I am creating a presentation in RevealJS using Quarto. The text of one of the slides is too long and gets truncated. Is there a way to automatically (or manually) adjust the font size to make the text fit into one slide? Here is a MWE:

```
---
title: "My slides"
format:
    revealjs:
        embed-resources: true
        transition: slide
output: 
    revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
        css: styles.css
execute:
    echo: TRUE
---

# This is fine

- Topic 1
   - Level 1
   - Level 2
   - Level 3

# This does not fit

- Topic 2
   - Level 1
   - Level 2
   - Level 3
- Topic 3
   - Level 1
   - Level 2
   - Level 3
- Topic 4
   - Level 1
   - Level 2
   - Level 3
```

Comment: This section [content overflow](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/index.html#content-overflow) from quarto doc might help you!

Comment: It helped indeed! If you want to make it an answer, I think it would be of help for other newbies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can follow the suggestions from the section [Content Overflow](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/index.html#content-overflow) to use the class `.smaller` to use smaller font for a slide if it contains too much content and even can make the content scrollable by using the `.scrollable` class.

```
---
title: "My slides"
format: revealjs
execute: 
  echo: true
---

# This is fine

- Topic 1
   - Level 1
   - Level 2
   - Level 3

# This does not fit {.scrollable .smaller}

- Topic 2
   - Level 1
   - Level 2
   - Level 3
- Topic 3
   - Level 1
   - Level 2
   - Level 3
- Topic 4
   - Level 1
   - Level 2
   - Level 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use columns (if the text isn't too wide, as in your example):

```markdown
---
title: "My slides"
format:
    revealjs:
        embed-resources: true
        transition: slide
output: 
    revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
        css: styles.css
execute:
    echo: TRUE
---

# This is fine

- Topic 1
   - Level 1
   - Level 2
   - Level 3

# This _does_ ~~not~~ fit

:::: {.columns}
::: {.column width="30%"}
- Topic 2
   - Level 1
   - Level 2
   - Level 3
:::
::: {.column width="30%"}
- Topic 3
   - Level 1
   - Level 2
   - Level 3
:::
::: {.column width="30%"}
- Topic 4
   - Level 1
   - Level 2
   - Level 3
:::
::::
```

[image]